# Canon 60D screen turned black when I’m at mode settings

Tags: canon, camera-settings, repair, camera, canon-60d

Starting from yesterday, my canon 60D camera’s screen will turn black when I’m at mode setting screen. When I press the Q button to change the ISO or the manual focus. The screen works again. What’s wrong?

I tried turning the camera off and removing the battery but that didn’t help at all.

Comment: Do you mean black (not back)?

Comment: Yea, it turned ‘black’ typo

Comment: What is "mode setting screen?"